# How can I roll back xserver-xorg-core and xserver-common?

Tags: apt, xorg, downgrade

A recent update to Xorg broke my desktop, which now looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbBxh.jpg]

In short, the desktop background is not updating on the secondary display. (And if there is no secondary display, the primary display background stops updating.)

Looking into the history, I found that this happened right after upgrading two packages:

- xserver-xorg-core
- xserver-common

These were upgraded to 1.9.0-0ubuntu7.3.

I'd like to downgrade these packages. How do I do that?

I've checked that both have another version in the maverick repo:

```
xserver-xorg-core:
  Installed: 2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7.3
  Candidate: 2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7.3
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7.3 0
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7 0
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main amd64 Packages
```

However, apt won't let me downgrade them:

```
ville@fluxx ~ % sudo apt-get install xserver-common=2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7 xserver-xorg-core=2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-core : Depends: xserver-xorg but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

And this is the reason:

```
ville@fluxx ~ % sudo apt-get install xserver-common=2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7 xserver-xorg-core=2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7 xserver-xorg-core

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-core : Depends: xserver-common (>= 2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7.3) but 2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Am I out of options here?

Comment: off-topic it reminds me of xp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be simple enough:

- Search for the appropriate packages in Launchpad

  - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/amd64/xserver-common/2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7
  - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/amd64/xserver-xorg-core/2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7
- Download packages
- run `sudo dpkg -i` on the packages

However, this didn't solve my problem. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Synaptic is also able to downgrade packages: Right-click in the needed package, choose "Force version" and select an older version. Then click on the apply button.

Comment: AFAIK, this is equivalent to downgrading packages using apt, which in this case didn't work.

Comment: Yes but synaptic should be able to make the dowgrade to the dependencies too.